# Two dimensional arrays(dynamically) if condition for null in c

Tags: c, if-statement, multidimensional-array, dynamic

Hi people I created an array that is two-dimensional dynamically. I want to determine which row empty but my syntax knowledge is insufficient. Thank you in advance for your interest.

There is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i,j,*x,y=0;
    int** p=malloc(sizeof(int*)*4);
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        p[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            p[i][j]=(y++);
    }
    x=NULL;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        // Fourth index shouldn't be NULL?
        if(p[i]==x)
            printf("NULL");
        else
            printf("Not null");
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        free(p[i]);
    free(p);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `for(i=0;i<3;i++)  p[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*3);` makes more sense with `for(i=0;i<4;i++)` or follow original code with `p[3] = NULL;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory returned by `malloc` is *uninitialized, so you can't do a NULL check on it.

If you instead use `calloc`, that initializes the memory to all bytes 0 so that you *can* check for NULL.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Is there any other solution for instance checking with 'sizeof'  ?

Comment: @FatihÖner `sizeof` will only give you the size of a pointer, not what it points to.  Even if it did work that way, that still wouldn't tell you what was set and what wasn't

Comment: Thank you so much I will use 'calloc'.